# Restoring a differential backup in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, backup, restore

I have created a full back up of my database by executing the line below in my application:

```
Dim Query As String = "backup database Ari to disk='G:\Documents and Settings\i\Desktop\BKAR\" & MyTime.getFullCurrentDate.Replace("/", "") & ".Bak'"
```

The `*.bak` file created successfully.

Then I restored it on another Database called test and it was ok. Then I created a differential backup by means of the following code:

```
Dim Query As String = "BACKUP DATABASE Ari TO DISK='G:\Documents and Settings\i\Desktop\BKAR\" & MyTime.getFullCurrentDate.Replace("/", "") & ".Bak'" & "WITH DIFFERENTIAL"
```

and it created a `*.bak` file ,but when I try to restore it on the database I mentioned as test ,I receive the following error: 
[image]
Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When restoring a sequence of backups (differential & logs) you specify `NORECOVERY`. This leaves the database in a state that will accept further restores, rather than recover it ready for use.

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyDb FROM DISK = '<path>\MyDb_FULL.bak' WITH NORECOVERY;
RESTORE DATABASE MyDb FROM DISK = '<path>\MyDb_DIFF.bak' WITH NORECOVERY;

-- Repeat following for each transaction log to restore if applicable
RESTORE LOG MyDb FROM DISK = '<path>\MyDb_201303050900_LOG.bak' WITH NORECOVERY;

RESTORE DATABASE MyDb WITH RECOVERY;
```

Comment: I'm really a beginner,is it possible to use the designer to restore the database in nonrecovery mode?

Comment: Yes, in the restore options look for 'Recovery state'. Default is 'Restore with recovery', change to 'Restore with norecovery'. This is covered in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188223.aspx).

Comment: Thanks,but when I try to restore in this mode,the restore operation continues until restarting the SQLServer service !I want to make an app for this goal,and I don't want to make the user stop and start the service !please suggest me a solution!

Comment: Read the documentation. The final backup that you restore you need to specify WITH RECOVERY, or issue a separate recovery command as per the last line in the script in my answer. But, are you sure this is something you should be building into an application when you don't appear to understand the fundamentals of SQL Server backups?

Comment: Thanks a lot,this time my problem has been solved by your answer,but I try to study SQL server more deeply  !